# Mouse cursor is not changing on WebGL

Tags: c#, html, unity-game-engine, mouse-cursor, unity-webgl

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic; 
 using UnityEngine;

 public class mouseScript : MonoBehaviour {

 public Texture2D cursorTexture;
 public CursorMode cursorMode = CursorMode.Auto; 
 public Vector2 hotSpot = Vector2.zero;

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {

 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {

 }
 void OnMouseEnter()
 {
     Debug.Log("texture mouse " + cursorTexture + "  cusor visiblity" + Cursor.visible); 
     Cursor.SetCursor(cursorTexture, hotSpot, cursorMode);
 }
 void OnMouseExit()
 {
     Cursor.SetCursor(null, Vector2.zero, cursorMode);
 }

}
```

I changed the mouse image properties:

- texture type - cursor
- read/write - enable html5 - override for webgl
- max size - 32
- format - RGB
- compressed - DXT1

I used this coding to change the mouse cursor. In unity editor it was working correctly, when I export to html5 mouse, cursor is not changing.

When I debug the scene in browser it displays an error like this:

> Error loading this URL: Could not load the source for blob:http://localhost:56077/f3a83177-83ac-4798-81fe-1b07da4548c2.
>   [Exception... "Failed to open input source 'file:////localhost:56077/f3a83177-83ac-4798-81fe-1b07da4548c2'"  nsresult: "0x80520001 (NS_ERROR_FILE_UNRECOGNIZED_PATH)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://devtools/shared/DevToolsUtils.js :: mainThreadFetch :: line 518"  data: yes]
>   Stack: mainThreadFetch@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://devtools/shared/DevToolsUtils.js:518:5
>   _getSourceText/<@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://devtools/server/actors/source.js:393:27
>   process@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:922:23
>   walkerLoop@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:806:7
>   scheduleWalkerLoop/<@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:742:11
>   Line: 518, column: 0

Comment: While my comment won't solve your problem exactly, you could create a [Javascript plugin](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html) to change the class of the HTML body element. Then, according to the class of the body, you would be able to [change the cursor image in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property)

Answer (score 3):

I assume this is WebGL. Last time I tried to use the `Cursor` API with `CursorMode.Auto` option on WebGL, it didn't work and should be considered a bug.

I had to use `CursorMode.ForceSoftware` for WebGL and `CursorMode.Auto` for other 
builds with the help of the `UNITY_WEBGL` macro.

```
#if UNITY_WEBGL
        Cursor.SetCursor(cursorTexture, hotSpot, CursorMode.ForceSoftware);
#else
        Cursor.SetCursor(cursorTexture, hotSpot, CursorMode.Auto);
#endif
```

---

Note that if this does not still work then you have to make your own Cursor API which is really easy.

Simply disable the main cursor with `Cursor.visible = false;` then use a fake mouse pointer texture and set its position with `Input.mousePosition`.

Another option is to make a Javascript plugin but that should be a last resort solution.

Comment: if i use CursorMode.ForceSoftware ,then both custom and default mouse cursor is visible. i used Cursor.visible = false statement,but still mouse cursor is visible

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting the same problem that my hand cursor was not showing in webgl build. So i took @programmer answer and here is the modified version that worked for me:

```
#if UNITY_WEBGL
        float xspot = cursor.width / 2;
        float yspot = cursor.height / 2;
        Vector2 hotSpot = new Vector2(xspot, yspot);
        Cursor.SetCursor(cursor, hotSpot, CursorMode.ForceSoftware);
#else
         Cursor.SetCursor(cursor, Vector2.zero, CursorMode.Auto);
#endif
```

With additional step of setting with image, I set my image size to 32 in image import settings.

Answer (score 0):

just set in Playersetting default Cursor.run in chrome browser.
you need to put a software called "NetBox2.exe" with unityWebGL in a same directory.
run it , input "http://localhost/mygame/" in browser.